# error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations

Tags: r, linux, package, tmap

I'm trying to install **tmap** package on R and it requires **lwgeom**

But when it comes to install 'lwgeom' I get this error:

> configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations. ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘lwgeom’

I've tryed to install **libproj-dev** but I've already got it.

I've also installed **rgdal** package sucessfully but I still got this error

I run on R-studio on Linux Mint 19

how to fix it and install **tmap**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider installing source from github https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom

Or wait for a new upcoming 0.2-4 version of lwgeom.
That error was fixed 2 days ago.
You may also install older version 0.2-2 which is correct.

Comment: Actually, I had to install an even older version lwgeom 0.1-7. This is the only one that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Lwgeom 0,2-5 has been released. I've installed it with success (R 4.0.1, Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing the lwgeom package directly, by using

```
install.packages("lwgeom", configure.args=c("--with-proj-include=/usr/local, --with-proj-lib=/usr/local"))
```

in your R console; of course using a proper path to your PROJ location (mine happens to live in `/usr/local`, but you will want to double check).

Comment: I searched `locate proj_api.h` and received 

"/usr/include/proj_api.h"

than : 

`install.packages("lwgeom", configure.args=c("--with-proj-include=/usr/include, --with-proj-lib=/usr/include"))`

still: 

"configure: pkg-config proj exists, will use it
checking proj_api.h usability... no
checking proj_api.h presence... no
checking for proj_api.h... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations."